# How can i solve KeyPress with backspace issue

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm pretty new with this and need help.
I have a private sub:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles textbox1.KeyPress
    Dim strCurrency As String = ""
    
    strCurrency = strCurrency & e.KeyChar
    
    If strCurrency.Length = 0 Then
            textbox1.Text = ""
    ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar)
        textbox1.Refresh()
        textbox1.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 3) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 3, 2)
        End If
    textbox1.Select(strCurrency.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

The point is, i want to put "." on text box like the currency format. Example: 123.456, 12.345 etc.
When i input the number, it work well, but when i backspace, its gonna be wrong.
I already debug using `Messagebox.show(strCurrency)` and `Messagebox.show(strCurrency.Lenght)` and count it with this logic:
`textbox1.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 3) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 3, 2)`

But the result went wrong. The result be 1.2 when the textbox i input 12345 and i backspace 1 times.

Comment: You need to process backspace differently - starting from not adding it to strCurrency. Generally it is quite nasty to format/alter input strings while typing (have you considered old clipboard shortcuts like Shift+Insert etc, which work nicely, but break your logic); better would be manipulate text while/after leaving the textbox.

Comment: thanks for your advice. But i can't manipulate text after leaving the textbox.
i really need this event to help the admin avoid wrong input the nominal. And also make this user friendly

Comment: Use the Validating event instead, fires after the user is done typing.  Or use MaskedTextBox to force a format up front.  Never use MessageBox to debug, use a breakpoint instead.

Comment: thanks for your advice. im already solved this issue using 'for' and modulus :)
Thank you